# Which block cipher for a very short (40-bit) message?

Tags: encryption

**Question:**

**I'm trying to encrypt a 32-bit message to produce a ciphertext no longer than 40 bits. Are there vetted block ciphers or other good ways to encrypt very short messages?** Are there any well-known ciphers with a block size this small?

---

**Context and motivation:**

Video games for retro platforms may have a campaign longer than one sitting but no nonvolatile memory for storing the campaign's state. To continue a campaign across a power cycle, the game issues a "[password](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Password_%28video_gaming%29)" and has the player enter it next time. This password is a short encrypted message containing the state of a campaign plus some extra bits used to ensure that randomly entered passwords or passwords with a few bits flipped are unlikely to work. For this application, the 32-bit message includes which chapter the player is on, quest flags, money, experience, and the like. A typical password has 8 characters with 32 possibilities (5 bits) per character (digits, consonants, and hyphen), for a total of 40 bits. Longer passwords are far more tedious to write down and key in.

I'm unaware of any well-known cipher with such a short block size. Ciphertext stealing works when is longer than one block but not an exact multiple of a cipher's block size. For example, if there were a 32-bit block cipher, one could encrypt the first 32 bits and then the last 32 bits, which touches the middle 24 bits twice. But as far as I can tell, it doesn't apply to a message shorter than a block. So currently I'm using a homemade cipher (yes, eww) with a structure inspired by [XXTEA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XXTEA), with five 8-bit words instead of several 32-bit words. After packing the campaign's state into the first 32 bits, I pad the remaining bits with a constant before encryption and reject passwords where the padding does not decrypt to the desired constant. Is there something better for a 40-bit block than rolling your own?

Encryption and decryption need to run on an 8-bit microprocessor in under a million cycles. I'm worried about online attacks and pencil-and-paper attacks by bored gamers, as have been posted in the "Classified Information" section of *Nintendo Power* magazine. But I'm not quite as concerned about automated attacks by someone reading the algorithm and symmetric key out of the game's code and using this information to put a password generator on a website, as this would take conscious effort on a player's part to cheat at the game.

Comment: Why not use One-Time-Pads? If your campaign-state fits into 40bits you could as well enumerate levels (or sth. similar). Assign the levels fixed passwords (e.g. "bootcamp" or "frog"). If your game gains attention the level passwords will appear on cheat-websites anyways.

Comment: Why limit the password length to 8 characters?

Comment: @marstato Isn't OTP encryption something you could conceivably do with pencil and paper?

Comment: @SteveSether No, why should it? Entirely depends on the algorithm used with the OTP. I meant the QS should use "random" passwords and assign them to campaing states instead of encrypting the campaign state itself.

Comment: @marstato You could do that, but it could take a huge amount of storage.  2^32 passwords ~= 4 billion.  You'd need to store a rather large lookup table somewhere.

Comment: Why would you use anything other than XOR if you're using an OTP? The only way to compromise an OTP is to get the key.

Comment: If you're distributing this game to the public, then your pads are not One Time.

Comment: @marstato Note that a simple XOR OTP is vulnerable to tampering. ("I wonder what happens if I flip this bit? Ooh, that treasure chest opens. What if I flip this bit? Ooh, now I'm 4 levels ahead.")

Comment: I believe i am being misunderstood: If possible, campaign progress should be bound to predefined passwords: "frog" -> level 1 done, "kitchen" -> level 2 done and so forth; no encryption at all.

Comment: @marstato "bootcamp" and "frog" encode which chapter the player is on (4 bits), but not cash, experience, or quest flags (the other 28 bits).

Comment: @SteveSether As is written in the question: "Longer passwords are far more tedious to write down and key in."

Comment: Do you really need a block cipher? Seems a stream cipher should do nicely. Given your threat model, even RC4 (which is outright trivial to implement) is probably more than sufficient. The length of the ciphertext output will be the same as the length of the plaintext input, plus anything you want to add to it yourself.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling: he wants an encryption with a MAC: game state data + some extra "redundancy bits" (e.g. set to 0) to reject invalid passwords; with 10 extra bits, only 1/1024 passwords will be accepted, and it still leaves 22 bits to encode game data. If he uses a stream cipher, the MAC part will be trivial to work around. Also, with RC4, players may infer the start of a password corresponding to some specific game data, and be left to an exhaustive search on the MAC part -- some will be bored enough to try a thousand passwords.

Comment: A simple XOR OTP is vulnerable to the kind of tampering the OP is concerned about.  pencil+paper hacking.  Realistically, any modern cipher that supports 32 bit blocks would fit the attacker model, since getting the key is going to be trivial which is MUCH easier than attacking the cipher.  Hell, you might even publish the method you used just to take the fun out of "hacking it".  An early custom crafted OS at MIT had a "crash system" command for this very purpose.

Comment: @ThomasPornin What's to say the MAC bits have to be at the end? They could be interleaved with the ciphertext, or even plaintext. Sure, still possible to work around, but much less obvious.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling The attacker model is "bored gamer who likes crossword puzzles".  It's not "average developer who might be discouraged by something non-obvious".

Comment: Another option to de-incentivize cheaters.  Add a "cheat code" bit, and provide a means for players to generate their own cheat codes that turns the cheat code bit on.  Then when someone uses a cheat code, put up something on the screen indicating a cheat code was used.  This provides gamers with a means to explore the game however they wish, but also lets anyone else know they used this mode.  Obviously someone could crack the generator and make their own, but it's less fun, and it's sort of "going to far", like you're saying.  Nethack, for instance allows go into explore mode.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The generic name for that kind of stuff is [format-preserving encryption](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Format-preserving_encryption). The [Thorp shuffle](http://www.cs.ucdavis.edu/~rogaway/papers/thorp.pdf) is a nice candidate, provided that you use an adequate round function (e.g. truncated output for a cryptographically secure hash function) and enough rounds, as indicated in the paper.

That being said, with 1 million cycles on an 8-bit computer, it may be hard to run, say, a 64-round Thorp shuffle with a truncated SHA-1 as round function.

Unfortunately, there is no standard, well-studied block cipher with short blocks and good performance on small architectures. On the other hand, your attack model states that attackers won't try really hard, so you don't need absolute crypto-grade security; a construction which is academically weak may still be strong enough for you.

I suggest you skim through [this page](https://www.cryptolux.org/index.php/Lightweight_Block_Ciphers) that lists "lightweight block ciphers" with some analysis. Some of them offer 32-bit block size. What you need is such a block cipher, such as there is a known attack on a reduced number of rounds, thereby indicating that some cryptographers tried to break it, and did not succeed for the full cipher. From a cursory look, at least KATAN, KTANTAN, SIMECK-32, SIMON-32 and SPECK-32 match these criteria; RC5 might also be usable with an adequate number of rounds.

Comment: [This paper](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1208.1176v2.pdf) claims to usually achieve better bounds than the Thorp shuffle. ​ ​

Comment: Beware of patents.  RC5 is a patented algorithm, and I'm unsure when it expires.  Check if the algorithm is still patented.

Comment: US Patent 5724428 was filed in 1995 (_after_ the publication of RC5, so that should be a US-only patent) and, as far as I know, patents expire 20 years after being filed, so it _should_ be expired. But, of course, I am not a lawyer and certainly not a lawyer specialized in patent law.

Comment: You're right.  The patent expires in the US 20 years after the filing date.  I wouldn't be as confidant about patents in other countries.

Comment: @SteveSether - I think the US is the only country that allows filing of post-publication patents. In other countries, once you publish the work (or ship a product based on the work) without a patent, the work is in the public domain and can never be patented. So Thomas P is saying that it can't be patented in other countries.

Comment: Specifically, I am saying that the only patent on RC5 I am aware of is the US patent, and that one should have expired by now.

Comment: Thorp shuffle in a nutshell: "Pop each bit off the front, XOR it by some uniform, round-dependent hash of the remaining bits, and push it on the back." XXTEA has a similar structure, except operating on a word level rather than a bit level. After reading the Thorp shuffle paper, I guess the biggest thing my homemade cipher appears to lack is round dependence in the hash function. I'll read the swap-or-not paper that Ricky Demer cited later.